# mongodb query documents which have subset of all key value pairs mentioned in the query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's assume we have the following documents in the Mongo db

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Jack",
    "info": {
      "eyes": "brown",
      "city": "paris",
      "accomodation": "house"
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "Mathew",
    "info": {
      "eyes": "yellow",
      "city": "rome",
      "accomodation": "apartment"
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "Peter",
    "info": {
      "eyes": "brown",
      "city": "barcelona",
      "accomodation": "house",
      "hair_color": "black"
    }
  }
]
```

Let's say the input JSON is

```
{
    "eyes": "brown",
    "city": "paris",
    "accomodation": "house",
    "hair_color": "black"
}
```

I would like to construct a query such that all the key-value pairs of the document should be present in the input json document but not necessarily the other way round.
For the above example - the output should be

```
{
    "Name": "Jack",
    "info": {
      "eyes": "brown",
      "city": "paris",
      "accomodation": "house"
    }
  }
```

Since all the key value pairs of `Jack` were met by the input json document even though the input JSON document had `hair_color` which wasn't present in `Jack` document

Mongo playground with input : https://mongoplayground.net/p/1T0ZL8yGhPW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is convert both your input and `info` field to an array using [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) and check if their if there's any none matches, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      rawInput: { // better if you do this in code once and drop this stage.
        "$objectToArray": {
          "eyes": "brown",
          "city": "paris",
          "accomodation": "house",
          "hair_color": "black"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          {
            $size: {
              $filter: {
                input: {
                  "$objectToArray": "$info"
                },
                as: "elem",
                cond: {
                  $not: {
                    "$in": [
                      "$$elem",
                      "$rawInput"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      Name: 1,
      info: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cNeCheaiiso)

Comment: Thanks for your response . I'm not sure if this addresses the question for the following reasons :
1. While calling "FindOne", we cannot provide "Name: Jack" as a parameter as we wouldnt know in advance if Jack has all the above attributes like eyes, city, accommodation etc
2. We don't really know which fields should match . Its like a subset problem . Assuming you have set A which is the input json , set B which is the json in the mongo db . We should satisfy "B is a subset of A" and not necessarily "A a subset of B"

Comment: I think what I'm looking for is a way to check if "a json is contained within another json" in mongodb . Similar to the "@>" or "<@" JSONB operators in postgresql . Ref  : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html

Comment: So technically you want to match ALL the documents in the collection and then project the matching keys/values? an empty set is still a subset of the input

Comment: I don't really want to project the matching key/values. I'm completely fine if the entire document is thrown back by mongodb . We could make an assumption that the  "info" part of the document in mongo db is never empty nor is "input" .

Comment: Would "jack" still match if this was the document? ```{
    "Name": "Jack",
    "info": {
      "eyes": "brown",
      "city": "paris",
      "accomodation": "house",
       anotherField: "123"
    }
  }```

Comment: No it wouldn't because "anotherField" isn't present in input. All key/values in info should be present in input but not necessarily the other way round.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response . Your query does satisfy the requirement . Could you take a look at this query as well , I tried to simplify it a bit - https://mongoplayground.net/p/bHq75SmLVjb . Does it cover the same cases?

Comment: Yep, it appears to be wroking well